# How can I solve my problem posting number sign to make a hashtag?

Tags: javascript, html, post, special-characters, hashtag

I'm trying to post # sing to make some words turn to hashtags but the code doesn't work and it's via API using this code:

```js
true == function()
{
var getMyItem = function (str)
{
if (sessionStorage.getItem(str) == null)
{
setMyItem(str, 0);
return 0;
}
return sessionStorage.getItem(str);
}
var setMyItem = function (key, value)
{
sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function bot(post)
{
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var Token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Token
var ID= "xxxxxx";
var url= 'https://bot.xxx/api/'+Token+'/sendMessage?text='+post+'&chat_id='+ID;
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
}
// you need to change the url variable contents for your own Telegram API or those of the same SN APIs..
```

So  when it comes to call the post like with this code:

```js
var myDate = new Date().toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
var post_n = "%23Hi. It's: " + myDate + "\n";
var post = encodeURI(post_n);

if (getMyItem(key + "htr") != "yes")
{
bot(post);
setMyItem((key + "htr"),"yes");
}


return true;
}
}()
```

, it doesnt support # sign in my browsers including Chrome an Firefox and nothing is sent actually.
So if it were for Telegram, the bot would look like this (and I donno if it works or not but I'm talking about another SN):
var url= 'https://api.telegram.org/'+Token+'...

Please tell me how to send # code. By the way, "%23" doesn't work.

Comment: If `%23` doesn't work then that's probably a limitation of the API

Comment: `true == function()` what's that for?

Comment: It's server special.

Comment: No. The API has been responsible for various people and I saw the results containing hashtags from them. Donno what's wrong with mine

Comment: Looks like no one is interested!